# how to add in to existing value in table column with magento update query?

Tags: mysql, magento

Trying:

```
Mage::getModel('module/table')
       ->setId($obj->getId()) //"using _afterSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $obj)"
       ->setCounter(+2) //"want to add to existing integer in table column"
       ->save();
```

on enable log-all-queries the sql statement:

```
SQL: UPDATE `table` SET `counter` = ? WHERE (id='2')
      BIND: array (
       0 => 1,
     )
```

trying to add into existing value (int) in table column (int) on each update with magento model. but as its clear in sql statement, not happening.
How can i achieve that?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by using zend dp expr

```
Mage::getModel('module/table')
           ->setId($obj->getId()) //"using _afterSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $obj)"
           ->setCounter(new Zend_Db_Expr('counter + 1')) //"want to add to existing integer in table column"
           ->save();
```

SQL Statement:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `counter` = counter + 1 WHERE (id='2')
```

regards,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to increment the current value of `counter` by 1.

Assuming `$obj->getCounter()` contains the current counter value, you could do it like this:

```
Mage::getModel('module/table')
    ->setId($obj->getId())
    ->setCounter($obj->getCounter() + 1) // increment counter by 1
    ->save();
```

Comment: this didn't work for me. but i got it solved.. thank you so much for you valuable time and answer.